# How to retrieve data from Rdio API using PHP?

Tags: php, api, rdio

I can't get the Rdio PHP API to work (i.e. retrieve some meaningful data). I need to write a simple function for fetching info about track / album stored in a ShortCode.

I am using PHP version of this:
https://github.com/rdio/rdio-simple

And this is my PHP code:

```
require_once 'rdio.php';

$rdio = new Rdio(array("MyClientID", "MyClientSecret"));

$request = $rdio -> call("getObjectFromShortCode", array("short_code" => "SomeShortCode"));

return $request;
```

However, when I do print_r() on the function output, there is no output at all.

I am a bit confused about how to initialize the API and get the response. The Rdio developer documentation itself doesn't give me a clue when trying to resolve the issue.

Would you mind telling me how to properly retrieve data using PHP from the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rdio PHP library currently doesn't support OAuth 2.0. You can try using a [generic OAuth 2.0 library](http://oauth.net/2/) to make requests.